# Filter array in PHP based on logical expressions

Tags: php, filter

I’m trying to implement a filter function in PHP. My two-dimensional input array looks like the following:

```
name(string)    age(integer)    reg_date(date)
----------------------------------------------
John            22              12/03/2015
Anne            23              14/04/2015
Marry           24              01/02/2015
Tim             55              13/03/2015
```

What I want is a filter that can take a logical expression and apply it to the input source like the following (own draft):

```
{name:'age' type:'integer', operator:'==', value:'23'} OR {name:'age' type:'integer', operator:'==', value:'24'} AND {name:'reg_date' type:'date', operator:'>', value:'12/03/2015', format:'d/m/Y'}
```

Expressed in words: Give me all entries where variable age is 23 or 24 and variable reg_date is later than 12/03/2015

For each datatype (type), a filter should exist that should be able to process datatype dependent operations (for example, a date-filter should use the format field to parse the date in the correct format). It should easily be possible to add new datatypes.

The correct output for the expression above would be

```
name(string)    age(integer)    reg_date(date)
----------------------------------------------
Anne            23              14/04/2015
```

My question: Do I have to write my own lexer to parse the logical expression (which could become rather complex) and apply a filter I’ve written on my own or do filter functions I need already exist? I tried to parse my array into an XML structure and use XPath, unfortunately XPath 1.0 which is used by PHP cannot handle date formats. I took a look at filter_var in the PHP Filter class, but it looks like logical expressions cannot be used there.

Comment: Can't you do this from the db? Actually it seems the job for a db.. In case you need this on code I think you have to write it.

Comment: `"XPath 1.0 which is used by PHP cannot handle date formats"` - why don't you try convert it to a timestamp with [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/strtotime)? Also, I'd do what @borracciaBlu said. This is a job for the database.

Comment: You will have to make logical operators such as LIKE, IN, BETWEEN, etc. These are all in SQL. Could you expand on how your Array gets populated? Otherwise you're going to a do lot of sorting and looping to match your conditions.

Comment: Well the problem is that most of the data is stored in documents (I'm not to blame for this). I thought it would be a large overhead to write it into a datebase and do the queries there, especially because the data can also change continuously. The strtotime() operator is not an option since date formats like 03/12/15 are always treated as m/d/Y but in fact can be d/m/Y as well.

Comment: @ChristianVorhemus did you solve the issue without writing a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using array_walk() php function

Comment: That's actually a good start for the iteration, but I think the hardest part is the filtering based on logical operators. I fear there is no build-in function for this.